# Tailwind JIT not working with variables React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, jit

```
    <img
      src={project.image.fields.file.url}
      className={"hover:translate-y-[-" + 10 + "%]"}
    />
```

I try to translate y based on a variable, or hardcoded number, this doesn't work and idk why
but this does

```
    <img
      src={project.image.fields.file.url}
      className={"hover:translate-y-[-10%]"}
    />
```

Doesn't really makes sence to me but idk, What do you think?

Comment: That’s not supported. See dynamic class names in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could use the `style` attribute for truly dynamic properties:

```
<img class="hover:translate-y-[--y]" style={{ '--y': `-${10}%` }} />
```